# How to put close button on div without putting inside html using background?

Tags: html, css

I have a div who are show as rectangle block. i want to show in them on Right top corner a close image who used for remove them  like Windows have.

```
<div class="block"></block>
```

the especial thing i need to use in this that i not want to put HTML in the div and thing to do this using background image but another thing is i don't know how much div it's have because div have test who user type already.

if i put the background-position 619px 4px  that i am unsure that they work when div are much big or too small.

so can someone show me how i can do this

Comment: Do you just want to see the image on top-right only or want some action too? Showing it at top-right is easy with CSS but getting the action, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your close icon a few pixels off the right-top corner, you could do this:

You can add some transparent pixels to your background image to the right (the offset from the right side), then you can use:

```
background-position: right 3px;
```